# Clustering of similar items

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

There are items of data like this:

```py
item1 = {
  "path": "/some/path",
  "data": {
    "a": [0, 1, 2, ...], #numpy array
    "b": [4, 9, 4, ...], #numpy array
    "c": [7, 1, 0, ...], #numpy array
  }
}
```

And I compare each item with each other. After that I have pairs like this:

```py
pairs = []
pair = {
  "a": item1,
  "b": item2,
  "diff": 12345,
}
pairs.append(pair)
pair = {
  "a": item1,
  "b": item3,
  "diff": 987654,
}
pairs.append(pair)
```

And now I want clusters (groups) of all similar items. Items are similar the smaller the diff property is.

I assume this can be done somehow using data science methods but my data is not like a x,y coordinate system. (I added pandas tag, because I assume, it may be helpful here)

How can I arrange my items in clusters by using most similarity (=smallest diff attribute)?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. At first I reduced the item pairs by applying a threshold for diff (keep pairs having diff < 10000000).

Then I run this code to create the clusters (groups):

```py
@dataclass
class ImageInfo:
    path: Path
    histogram: RgbHistogram

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.path)


@dataclass
class Pair:
    a: ImageInfo
    b: ImageInfo
    diff: Optional[int]


ImageInfoGroup = set[ImageInfo]

#[...]

    def get_groups(self, pairs: list[Pair]) -> list[ImageInfoGroup]:
        groups: list[ImageInfoGroup] = []
        for pair in pairs:
            pair_in_groups = []

            # Search items in all groups
            for i, group in enumerate(groups):
                if pair.a in group or pair.b in group:
                    pair_in_groups.append(i)

            # If matching items were found in multiple groups, merge those groups
            if len(pair_in_groups) > 1:
                for group_id in reversed(pair_in_groups[1:]):
                    groups[pair_in_groups[0]].update(groups[group_id])
                    del groups[group_id]

            # Add items to the groups
            if len(pair_in_groups) > 0:
                groups[pair_in_groups[0]].update([pair.a, pair.b])
            else:
                groups.append(set([pair.a, pair.b]))

        return groups
```

This creates `groups` having one element for each group of similar items.